# How to create a vector with equivalent spacing between its consecutive elements in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I was wondering how to create a vector with equivalent spacing between its consecutive elements in R? In Matlab, I can do [start:step:end].

Also if I want to plot a function with analytical form, do I have to evaluate the function on some sample points in its domain and plot these pair of points? Is there a R function that can take the function form and a set in its domain as arguments, and plot the graph of the function on the set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `seq` as suggested by ars
2. For example,  `plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi)`.

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't know plot could do that.

Comment: Thanks! In examples like plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi), is there a default spacing for sampling the range in domain?

Comment: The default is 101 points. See help(plot.function).

Answer (score 3):

See [seq](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/i386_rhel3/lib/R/library/base/html/seq.html) for sequence generation:

```
seq(from, to, by)
```

or `?seq` for help.